# PHP - parsed information write to a file

Tags: php, json, file-io

For Background:
I would like parse time and value from several (json) files and put them into an array and write the information in a file!

My Question:

How can I create a file like this construction: 
http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

So

```
[
  [1101859200000,33.90], 
  [1101945600000,32.60],
  ...
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). those functions along with [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), and [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) should be what you need.